# Chrome Extension (Windows 10) - how to find crash log / report?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm running a Chrome Extension on a Windows 10 computer but sometimes it crashes and it's always when I'm not in front of the computer. I'd like to find a way to see what happened and find out the reason of the crash.

I have started chrome in debug mode with this:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ---enable-logging --v=1 ---vmmodule ---no-sandbox

I can't find a chrome_debug.log anywhere.

I see a couple of DMP files in the Chrome folder. I have tried to edit them with Windbg but the information I get out of it is very limited:

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for chrome_child.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for chrome_child.dll - 
rax=00000000aae79636 rbx=000266be30311920 rcx=000002d27ba72f40
rdx=000002d27ba76380 rsi=000000000000b880 rdi=0000000002b801d0
rip=00007ff802feaf07 rsp=000000f125dfdde0 rbp=000000f125dfde00
r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000140 r10=000002d200005c00
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000003 r13=00007ff8074875a9
r14=000002d27ddb0820 r15=0000518316a04000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=0000  ds=0000  es=0000  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
chrome_child!ChromeMain+0x419517:
00007ff8`02feaf07 3b03            cmp     eax,dword ptr [rbx]         ds:000266be`30311920=????????
```

That doesnt help me much unfortunately. My browser console crashed with the extension so I can't see there what happened. If I could may be have active logging on the console, that could help but I don't know how to do this.

The extension sometimes run fine for a couple of days and then suddenly it crashes, I don't really see a pattern here.

I have taken the "massage" option from wOxxOm here below and I get more information but again, it's not something that helps me very much as I don't see something related to the chrome extension:
[image]

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: WinDBG needs [some massage](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows/windbg-help). You can also view the dmp file in Visual Studio, just make sure to specify the debug symbols server as shown in windbg article or [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows). Note, there are lots of other articles on debugging Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I have done the massage you suggested, I indeed get more info but nothing that I can link to my extension. Do you have any idea of how I could get something specific for chrome extension crashes?

Comment: A crash inside JS garbage collector is definitely a bug in Chrome. You can try to report it on https://crbug.com but without a reliable repro sequence it might not get fixed. As for your extension, try to find the memory leaks in devtools memory snapshots or heap allocation profiler (also in devtools).